# how to restrict admin signing in through usersignin page passport authentication and mongodb

Tags: angularjs, passport.js

we are developing one e-commerce project in that i am signing in  admin page it automatically admin and user signing page. how we restrict to stop admin to user signing page. in this i am using passport authentication.

```
function ensureOnlyAdmin(req, res, next){
if(req.isAuthenticated()){
  if (req.user.role === 'admin')
  {
    return next();
  }
  else {

    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/admin');
   }

}
else {
    res.redirect('/admin');
}
```

}

above code for authentication

```
router.post('/admin', passport.authenticate('authAdminWeb', {successRedirect:'/admin/dashboard', failureRedirect:'/admin',failureFlash: true}),function(req, res) {res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');});
```

above code for posting

Comment: Could you clarify? the top code should work...

Comment: if entered person role is equal to admin that person only access the admin  page other wise we are not accepting the admin page